# В каком файле Oracle на Linux хранит данные?

Tags: oracle

Хочу понять на каком разделе у меня на сервере лежат данные.

Comment: Зависит от настроек. Oracle может вообще под данные отдельную партицию отвести, без файловой системы. Спросите лучше у админа базы.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, как у вас выглядит `$ORACLE_HOME`, написав `echo $ORACLE_HOME`, может быть станет понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/dfiles.htm

SELECT FILE_NAME, BYTES FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;

И вокруг, соответственно.